# How to authenticate and deploy a Next.JS App from CircleCI to Vercel

Tags: next.js, continuous-integration, netlify, circleci, vercel

I'm trying to create a CI-CD pipeline for my Next.JS app with CircleCI. I want to deploy the site after running tests etc in CircleCI. However, Vercel prompts me to log in via command line (in Circle CI) which I have no access to. It seems like, for Netlify, I can add environment variables which are `NETLIFy_AUTH_TOKEN` and `NETLIFY_SITE_ID`, and Netlify will pick this up automatically. I also want to achieve this in Vercel.

Output on CircleCI

[image: output in CircleCI]

In `.circleci/config.yml`

```
- run:
  name: "deploy to vercel"
  working_directory: packages/client
  command: |
    yarn vercel:deploy
```

Script in `package.json`

```
"vercel:deploy": "vercel --prod"
```

Comment: Hi Shane. Wondering if I can take a look at the complete content of your `.circleci/config.yml`. I need to use Vercel for deployment with CircleCI. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `--confirm` flag when using vercel cli in your pipeline. Here is one example on Gitlab CI it should be similar for CircleCI https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/4853